# View width 100% on mobile is more than 100% [React]

Tags: html, css, reactjs, mobile

I am trying to have a div cover 100% of the width on mobile (but no more) using the below code:

React code:

```
  <div className="max-width-100vw">
    HELLO I AM A SENTENCE THAT IS OVERFLOWING???
  </div>
```

CSS code:

```
.max-width-100vw {
  max-width: 100vw;
  width: 100%;
}
```

But when I look at what this produces on mobile using chrome dev tools I see that the div is taking up more than 100% of the viewer width:

[image]

Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can fix it? As a hack I could set width=50% and that does stop it from overflowing but i am looking for a more principled solution?

Comment: Can you update your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example of your issue, and possibly provide a live codesandbox or similar that accurately reproduces it? From the minute amount of code and image it's hard to know what could be going on.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake, it was just because I was zoomed in when looking at it in the developer console!